# Unable to populate spark custom metrics

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to publish custom metrics using Spark CustomMetric API as supported since spark 3.2 https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/31476,
[https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/connector/metric/CustomMetric.html](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/connector/metric/CustomMetric.html%C2%A0)

I have created a custom metric implementing `CustomMetic` with default constructor overriding name and description.  Created a new instance of the created custom metric in the `supportedCustomMetrics` method of  `spark.sql.connector.read.Scan`.

Created a custom task metric implementing `CustomTaskMetric` with the same name as that of CustomMetric class and initialized this in `currentMetricsValues` of `PartitionReader`.

I have static values as of now but when I run the application, I see in the spark history page the corresponding    value to the metric as **N/A**.  I have added logs in the `aggregateTaskMetrics` and my flow is going into it. The spark SQLAppStatusListener.aggregateMetrics is loading my class and calling the `aggregateTaskMetrics` yet I still see N/A in the spark ui page.

Driver log:

```
23/06/23 19:23:53 INFO Spark32CustomMetric: Spark32CustomMetric in aggregateTaskMetrics start
23/06/23 19:23:53 INFO Spark32CustomMetric: Spark32CustomMetric in aggregateTaskMetrics sum:1234end
+---------+----------+-------+-----------+
|     word|word_count| corpus|corpus_date|
+---------+----------+-------+-----------+
|     LVII|         1|sonnets|          0|
|   augurs|         1|sonnets|          0|
|   dimm'd|         1|sonnets|          0|
```

Am I missing something? Any help is really appreciated.   Thanks.

Spark UI page: [image]

Comment: After read the PR discussion there is a merging logic to be implemented which is run in the driver. Did you also provide such ?

Answer (score 0):

Spark uses drop-wizard metrics library to handle metrics and you need to export these metrics a time-series database such as `Graphite` or `Prometheus`

Comment: Yeah, but I wanted to use spark [custom metrics API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/connector/metric/CustomMetric.html) to publish the metrics not the drop-wizard which exports to sinks.

Answer (score 0):

Since spark-history server is a separate process, adding the jar which has the code for SparkCustom metrics in the classpath solved this.